# Xamarin.Forms UWP Size of Elements doesn't work

Tags: xaml, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin.
When I try to insert a Button or a BoxView I can set the "HeightRequest" and "WidthRequest" Parameters but the elements are just filling the whole screen.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done nothing wrong, but you missed some key procedure. you did not set `LayoutOptions` of `Button` or `BoxView`. The following code could make element size effected.

```
<Button Text="click me" 
 HeightRequest="44"
 WidthRequest="60" 
 VerticalOptions="Start"
 HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
```

As you know, the button control is inherited from the [`View`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/View.cs). The default value of `VerticalOptions` dependency property is [`LayoutOptions.Fill`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/View.cs#L15). And it also works for `HorizontalOptions`. So if you did not set value for `VerticalOptions` and `HorizontalOptions`, the control will fill the whole screen.

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much :)